# Gitlab CI/CD error Machine Learning Python

Tags: python, git, machine-learning, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have this written a RandomForest regression model in a class Modelrf. It is a separate python file named as RandomForest.py

Code for RandomForest.py:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd


class Modelrf():

    def __init__(self, train = "train.csv", test = "test.csv"):
        self.X_train = pd.read_csv(train)
        self.X_test = pd.read_csv(test)
        self.linear_reg = LinearRegression()
        self.random_forest = RandomForestRegressor()
    def split(self):
        self.X_train.dropna(axis=0, subset=['salary'], inplace=True)
        self.X_test.dropna(axis=0, subset=['salary'], inplace=True)
        self.y_train = self.X_train.final_hourly_fee
        self.y_test = self.X_test.final_hourly_fee

    def fit(self):
        self.model = self.random_forest.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

    def predict(self):

        self.result = self.random_forest.predict(self.X_test)
        return self.result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_instance = Modelrf()
    model_instance.split()
    model_instance.fit()
    model_instance.predict()
    print(model_instance.result)
    print("Accuracy: ", model_instance.model.score(model_instance.X_test, model_instance.y_test))

    output = pd.DataFrame({'Id': model_instance.X_test.index,'Y Original': model_instance.y_test, 'Y predicted':model_instance.result})
    output.to_csv('outputTest.txt', index=False)
```

Now I have imported the class Modelrf into main.py

Code for main.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from RandomForest import Modelrf
from RandomForest import X_test,y_test,result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_instance = Modelrf()
    model_instance.split()
    model_instance.fit()
    model_instance.predict()
    print(model_instance.result)
    print("Accuracy: ", model_instance.model.score(model_instance.X_test, model_instance.y_test))


    output = pd.DataFrame({'Id': model_instance.X_test.index,'Y Original': model_instance.y_test, 'Y predicted':model_instance.result})
    output.to_csv('outputTest.txt', index=False)
```

I want to enable CI/CD on gitlab how can I write my'.gitlab-ci.yml' file code?

Comment: You included your python code but your CI isn't using the python code and your question is about general CI?

Comment: @TinNguyen yes. I want to know in what way should I write my .yml file so that CI is able to push it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you need to go to your repository:
Settings > CI/CD > Runners
Then you need to decide if you wand to use a private or a shared runner:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/

Comment: will the shared runner work with the .yml file that I have created?

Comment: You used the tag "ci", I don't know if there is a shared runner with this tag. Runners pickup tasks that match their set of tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638979/understanding-gitlab-ci-tags
These tags usually indicate whether the runner supports the technology needed to run your CI stage. In your case you need a runner with the tag "shell" or "linux" etc. because of you script.

Comment: so how should I pick a compatible runner?

Comment: also when I created the runner I already added shell as a tag

Comment: make sure to activate shared runners under Settings > CI/CD > Runners and then the tag "gitlab-org" should do

Comment: I understood thanks. The tags part was the error. I'm accepting your answer.