# Gitlab runners with same tags

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have the following runners online

```
gitlab-runner-default:
tags: "default,high-priority"

gitlab-runner-high-priority:
tags: "high-priority"
```

Then I have a job which is using tag `default`, so `gitlab-runner-default` is occupied.

If I ran another job with tag `high-priority`, will it use `gitlab-runner-high-priority` or will it wait for `gitlab-runner-default` to be available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Gitlab CI tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638979/understanding-gitlab-ci-tags)

Comment: No that post is about git tag vs runner tag..

Answer (score 0):

Tested in GitLab Enterprise Edition 15.8.0-ee

It used `gitlab-runner-high-priority`